# I am attempting to import junit libraries but they are not being recognised

Tags: java, junit

I have these imports at the beginning of the file:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
```

I get an error saying the issue can not be resolved, this then means I am unable to use the @Test and assertEquals().

Can anyone help me with this? I have the 'hamcrest-core-1.3' as well as 'junit-4.12' files in my project location.

This is the code I have in my main file

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculatorTest 
{

    @Test
    public void testAdd1() // 1st test
    {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator(); // create a new object to be tested
        double result = calculator.add(10, 50); // try adding 50 to 10
        assertEquals(60, result, 0); // assertEquals() is used to check the testing result
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd2() // 2nd test
    {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator(); // create a new object to be tested
        double result = calculator.add(7.5, 1.5); // try adding 7.5 to 1.5
        assertEquals(10.0, result, 0); // check the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a build system like [gradle (`gradle.org`)](https://gradle.org/) or [maven (`maven.apache.org`)](https://maven.apache.org/)? If so: please [edit] the post and share the `build.gradle` / `pom.xml`.

Comment: "I get an error saying the issue can not be resolved". The precise error message would help